# Mobile Architecture Options with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am building an app that includes these design goals:

1. Fast and modular - lightweight core that can be expended into a feature rich app in a coherent manner
2. Mobile first - this app first and foremost targets mobile platforms. It uses some device native features. It must look and feel like a mobile app (with page transitions and swipe events). However, a large subset of its features must also be available to web browsers. My goal it to have one unified code base with a common core and mobile specific extensions.

So far, I have selected the following stack.

1. AngularJS: I have used a few JavaScript frameworks in my other projects. Angular seems to suit me best in terms of modularity and well thought out design. I want to use Angular native constructs (like directives) and minimize "other kinds" of JavaScript-based widgets from external UI toolkits.
2. Cordova: I am comfortable with its design philosophy and plug-in system. I am aware of performance considerations which emphasize the importance of choosing the right JavaScript framework.
3. Some responsive framework: Bootstrap 3 would be my preference at the time of writing. I like its looks. It's design seem sound. There are Angular directives available to replace it's jQuery plugins.
4. I have a well-defined REST API on the server-side which is bound to Angular resources. I am not planning on doing "presentation stuff" on the server.

**Here is my question:** On point 3, Bootstrap seems to be missing features to build an "advanced" a mobile app. Bootstrap responsive behavior is great for basic controls, but I need a little more. For example, things like page transitions and swipe events come for free with jQuery Mobile. While I do not expect to find this kind mobile features in Bootstrap, it seems like I should be able to include directives that would add things like page transitions and swipe events without overlapping with the Bootstrap CSS. There is angular-mobile-nav, does anyone use it in conjunction with Bootstrap? Or is Bootstrap just the wrong choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of late to this question but you should check out [**Ionic**](http://ionicframework.com/). It uses Angularjs and comes a bunch of great components (angular directives) and is pretty easy to get started with while still being powerful. I've been playing around with it for while and love it. Definitely a good direction for mobile apps.

Oh one last thing, they play well with cordova/phonegap

Comment: I agree. Ionic is the best. It was not around (or in early stages) when I posed the question. I since switched to Ionic. It responds to all the requirements stated in the problem description, whithout the overhead of some of these other frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same question myself lately. Bootstrap 3 is my preference, but I wish it had mobile events and animations built-in.  In addition to http://www.appgyver.com/steroids already mentioned, I've also come across http://ionicframework.com/ and https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-jqm.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen those as well. Perhaps angular-jqm would be my choice once it is a little further along and supports uses the jqm 1.4 CSS. Ionic also seems to have the right ideas. For now, I wrapped a clone of iOS7 headers/page transitions in Angular directives: https://github.com/fredfortier/angular-ios7

Answer (score 1):

Did you already have a look at http://www.appgyver.com/steroids it will play well with Angular and Cordova and will save you some of the troubles you mentioned in your question. Of course you can still keep bootstrap for more "basic" needs.

Answer (score 1):

All these answers are good. Both Steriods and Ionic look like great frameworks and acceptable solutions to the problem as described. For my particular problem, I created a very lightweight Angular module which adds iOS7 headers and animations on top of Bootstrap/Bootswatch themes: https://github.com/fredfortier/angular-ios7.

I wanted something very simple that lets me use mostly Bootstrap. For anything more complex, I would definitely consider Steroids or Ionic.